# How does this double recursive call display the data c++

Tags: c++

I am unsure how the following code displays the data that is in rChild and lChild. Before it gets to the display code, the function is called with the paramater ptr-rChild passed. So wouldn't the display code never get a chance to execute since there is always a function call before the display code. Also, when the function gets called again but this time the parameter is lChild, how does it display the data in lChild when the first function call with the parameter rChild is there.

```
void CTree::DisplayTree(PersonRec * ptr)
{
    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        DisplayTree(ptr->rChild);
        cout << "Name: " << ptr->name << "\t" << "Bribe Offered: " << ptr->bribe << endl;
        DisplayTree(ptr->lChild);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take the Tree below as an example where `Node0` is the first `PersonRec*` passed to `DisplayTree` (on the right side is the order that the nodes are visited for reference):

```
           Node0                       1st
          /     \                     /   \
     Node2       Node1             5th     2nd
    /    |       |    \           /  |     |  \
NULL  NULL       NULL  NULL    7th 6th     4th 3rd
```

- The first call enters the if statement and passes `Node1` to `DisplayTree` (as `rChild`)
- The second call enters the if statement and passes `NULL` to `DisplayTree` (as `rChild`)
- The third call does not enter the if statement because the argument is `NULL` and returns to the second call (`Node1`)
- **The second call now prints `Node1`** and then passes `NULL` to `DisplayTree` (as `lChild`)
- The fourth call does not enter the if statement and returns to the second call (`Node1`)
- The second call has finished and returns to the first call (`Node0`)
- **The first call now prints `Node0`** and then passes `Node2` to `DisplayTree` (as `lChild`)
- The fifth call enters the if statement and passes `NULL` to `DisplayTree` (as `rChild`)
- The sixth call does not enter the if statement and returns to the fifth call (`Node2`)
- **The fifth call now prints `Node2`** and then passes `NULL` to `DisplayTree` (as `lChild`)
- The seventh call does not enter the if statement and returns to the fifth call (`Node2`)
- The fifth call has finished and returns to the first call
- The first call has finished

**Edit**: Addressing your comment with a smaller example. Consider a tree that has only one node with no children, and lets focus on the code more this time. The tree would look like this:

```
     Node0
    /     \
NULL       NULL
```

The first time your code is called, `Node0` is passed in. `if (ptr != NULL)` is `true`, therefore execution enters the if statement. The next line, `DisplayTree(ptr->rChild);` calls the function with `NULL`. During that call, `if (ptr != NULL)` is `false` an so execution does not enter the if statement. As a result, execution returns to the previous call and the next line of code is `cout << "Name: " << ptr->name...` which prints `Node0`'s information, that is why there is output. The call after that line, `DisplayTree(ptr->lChild);` also would do nothing because it passes `NULL` and then all recursion is finished

Comment: That is still very confusing to me

Comment: @H.Lee, What part is confusing? Are you able to follow the example?

Comment: Well, how does the function keep running when pyr = NULL. Doesnt that break you out of the if statement? And when this happens, how is the program able to go back to previous function calls and print that data when another function called has been made already with a different parameter value.

Comment: @H.Lee, When the argument passed to `DisplayTree` is `NULL` then the call does nothing. As a result, it returns to where it was called from. I will extend my answer to make another example

Comment: Yes I understand now. I was looking at your diagram on mobile, and it was not showing the whole right tree. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It will always traverse the left child first.  As it gets to leaves on the left, it will start traversing the right side.

This is called "in order" recursion.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Comment: It traverses `rChild` first (which probably means right)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of 'Recursive functions' is simple but it can be a little intimidating at the first encounter. There are many good resources about this and I personally have enjoyed the following ones very much:

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D2N36Up4/

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson16.html

As you may know, function calls are placed on stack memory and since this memory is limited, once too many are called without ending, the program will crash. Therefore, an important part of a recursive definition is the stopping criteria which specifies when and under what circumstances, the function will stop calling itself and breaks the recursive cycle. In your code, the line `if (ptr != NULL)` is the stopping criteria. Hence, the answer to your question

> So wouldn't the display code never get a chance to execute since there is always a function call before the display code.

is that the recursive call of `DisplayTree` will end when it reaches the leaf of the tree where the `rChild` and `lChild` are `NULL`. That is when the `DisplayTree(ptr->rChild);` will return immediately for the leaf node and the `cout << "Name: " << ptr->name << "\t" << "Bribe Offered: " << ptr->bribe << endl;` line of code gets the chance to execute and print the data. Of course, it all depends on whether your tree is well-defined or not. From your code it can be assumed that the function expects the leaf node to have NULL values for rChild and lChild. So if the tree is constructed in accordance with this specification, the stopping condition will be met and the data will be displayed. On the other hand, if tree is not constructed correctly, your program will crash because of stack overflow (see [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow))

Comment: But what about when the left and right child of the parent node are not null. It wont break the if statement, so how would it get a chance to display data

Comment: @H.Lee It all depends on whether your tree is well-defined or not. From your code it can be assumed that the function expects the leaf node to have  NULL values for rChild and lChild. So if the tree is constructed in accordance with this specification, it will display the data. On the other hand, if tree is not constructed correctly, your program will crash because of stack overflow (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see a recursive function call, know that the function *will* return at some point and the next statement will be executed. But how? Well, `DisplayTree(ptr->rChild)` will keep calling itself and will stop when it receives a null pointer.  That is why your `if (ptr != NULL)` check is so important - it prevents infinite recursion and also logically you wouldn't want to dereference a null pointer.

When the function that received a null pointer returns, the compiler goes down the call stack to the last frame that made the call. There it will move on to the next statement. This will be when it will print the rightmost node in the tree. And then it will recursively call itself with `ptr->lChild` which will find the rightmost node in *that* tree, and begin the process over again.

This is an example of an inorder traversal. When I see a function like this I like to say to myself "this function executes the middle statement first for the right subtree, the current node, and then its left subtree" which makes it a whole lot more comprehensible.

Comment: When you say it passes ptr lChild and then searches the right most node in that tree, would it print the data in lChild only when the rChild is NULL?

Comment: @H.Lee Yes, only when a given node's right subtree is null will the recursive call return, the compiler will pop off the last stack frame, and go to the next statement of the previous stack frame (which is the `cout` statement). Then it will go to its left subtree and repeat the process for that subtree.

Comment: @H.Lee If you draw an image of a binary tree you can use your finger, starting from the root, and travel down the tree each node at a time for every function call. `display(p->right)` means move your finger to the right subtree, and `display(p->left)` means move to the left subtree. If a function returns (because `ptr == NULL`) go to the previous node that you came from and go to the next statement. After everything is done your finger should be back on the root.

Comment: So the program is able to print the data for the previous function call because it stores that data temporarily on the stack?

Comment: @H.Lee Yup, the flow of control is saved before calling a function. Then when the call returns, the flow of control resumes as normal. This is similar for normal function calls because there really is no difference between a normal function call and a recursive function call, the compiler does the same thing for both.